# I'm trying to use php to validate an email

Tags: php

I keep getting this error "Using $this when not in object context"

Instantiation.

```
$axre = new Axre();

if (!filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo"no";
}
```

How do i get in object context?

It's protected $email, i need it protected because it's on a form.

// Most objects in this framework are populated by calling the constructor, but
// this one has a variety of entry points.

```
class Axre extends Base {


protected $email;
protected $user_name;
protected $temp_token;
protected $sign_in_token;

protected $UserShoppingList;

function __construct($email = null) {

    if (strpos($email, '@') === false) {
        $this->sign_in_token = $email;
    } else {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}
```

Comment: because you are using `$this` out of object scope. Try `$axre->email`

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Shopper::$email

Comment: What is the name of the variable in which the email value is stored?

Comment: You'll have to show us the rest of the code if we are to make sense of this.

Answer (score 0):

The $this variable is a special reference to the current instance of a class. You are using outside of a class that doesn't make any sense.

**From the PHP examples**

```
class Vegetable {
   var $edible;
   var $color;

   function Vegetable($edible, $color="green") 
   {
       $this->edible = $edible; // $this refers to the instance of vegatable
       $this->color = $color;   // ditto
   }
}

$this->variable; //This does not make sense because it's not inside an instance method
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Axre extends Base {


protected $email;
protected $user_name;
protected $temp_token;
protected $sign_in_token;

protected $UserShoppingList;

function __construct($email = null) {

    if (strpos($email, '@') === false) {
        $this->sign_in_token = $email;
    } else {
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}

function isValidEmail() {
    if (filter_var($this->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Now to use it you can just instantiate the class and call the isValidEmail method to get a true/false result.

```
$test = new Axre($email);
$validEmail = $test->isValidEmail();
```

You can't use $this outside of a class and expect it to work.